Grid layout of 1->49 satisfying arithmetic sequences
We have the numbers from 1-49 which we like to arrange in a 7x7 Grid in such as fashion so that the sum of each row progresses in an arithmetic sequence of distance=7, and likewise, the sum of the columns as well form an arthmetic sequence with a distance=7 (This is the minimum possible distance)
Here is a sample arrangement shown to drive home the point:  In this example, the rows are arranged with the distance=25, but the columns are not correct and do not have a constant distance. Hence this arrangement is False altogether. (As it only satisfies the row sequences only)

Is there a simple method to use to compose this?
Does a constant d exist for higher nxn numbers? For example for 8x8, or 9x9, 10x10, etc...  And will the d always equal n? Or is the 7 a coincidence?

according to google AI, there is no algorithm to do this magic square. Need trial and error. Just google it and see. It gives how to start but then it says there is no known algorithm to fill the whole square other than trial and error.  Find the magic constant for the center row and column, then fill in the square using symmetry and trial and error.

Do you mean $n$ = grid size and $d$ = distance of sequence?

n is the number of rows and columns, hence it is nxn. Above is 7x7.     @Nasser:  not clear, why would it be difficult? Can Mathematica not try all possibilities and get the numbers to add up right for a constant d?  isn't mathematica fast/efficient  for "trial and error" part?

For $n=3$, {{1, 3, 9}, {4, 5, 6}, {8, 7, 2}} is a solution for $d=2$ and {{2, 1, 8}, {3, 5, 7}, {6, 9, 4}} for $d=4$. I don't know which $d$ is possible for $n=7$.

All possibilities mean 49!=608281864034267560872252163321295376887552831379210240000000000 cases. You cannot do it before our universe runs out.

No - i mean to do it in a more intelligent fashion: for example start off with some patterns such as the one I gave them move numbers around. Or use the method that Nasser suggested above.

Since you are looking for an algorithm, can I suggest stackexchange computer science under the algorithms  tag.   Once you have an algorithm, then you could implement it in Mathematica. But google AI says there is no algorithm for this (unless you consider trial and error an algorithm).

7 is not the minimum possible distance. There are magic squares that have distance 0 and I provided an explicit example with distance 1 in my answer.

First I will list all unique solution for n=3 and distance m=0,1,...,6 (for higher m there are no solutions).
fu3[m_] := 
 With[{n = 3}, 
  DeleteDuplicatesBy[
   Select[DeleteDuplicates[
     Transpose@SortBy[Transpose[#], Total] & /@ 
      DeleteDuplicates[
       SortBy[#, Total] & /@ (Partition[#, n] & /@ 
          Permutations[Range@(n^2), {n^2}])]], 
    Union@Differences[Total /@ #] == 
      Union@Differences[Total /@ Transpose@#] == {m} &], 
   Sort[Sort /@ Join[#, Transpose[#]]] &]]

Using the above function for all m:
(Grid[#, ItemSize -> 1, 
        Frame -> {None, 
          None, {{{1, 3}, {1, 3}} -> True}}] & /@ (Append[
          Append[#, Total@#] & /@ #, 
          Append[Total /@ Transpose@#, 
           Style[#[[2]] - #[[1]] &@Total[#], Red]]] & /@ fu3[#]) // 
     Multicolumn) & /@ Range[0, 8] // Column[#, Frame -> All] &



It is easy to see that from the magic square (for m=0) we can create all other squares for different m by swapping two appropriate elements whose difference is equal to m. Then sort rows and columns by their increasing sum.
For higher n it can be done the same way. Starting with magic square and then swapping elements and sorting the square.
For n=7 and m=1 I did it just by sight inspection of magic square and realizing which elements should be swapped.
ResourceFunction["MagicSquare"][7];
Grid[#, ItemSize -> 2, 
   Frame -> {None, None, {{{1, 7}, {1, 7}} -> True}}] & /@ (Append[
     Append[#, Total@#] & /@ #, 
     Append[Total /@ Transpose@#, 
      Style[#[[2]] - #[[1]] &@Total[#], Red]]] & /@ {%})



It is not hard to see that swapping pairs {{38, 39}, {11, 12}, {46, 48}, {2, 4}} do the job.
ResourceFunction["MagicSquare"][
   7] /. (Join[Rule @@@ #, Rule @@@ Reverse /@ #] &@{{38, 39}, {11, 
      12}, {46, 48}, {2, 4}});
Grid[#, ItemSize -> 2, 
   Frame -> {None, None, {{{1, 7}, {1, 7}} -> True}}] &@(Append[
     Append[#, Total@#] & /@ #, 
     Append[Total /@ Transpose@#, Style["-", Red]]] &@%)



Now just sorting rows and column by their sum:

As a list it is:
{{28,2,11,45,29,37,20},{46,24,32,16,7,8,40},{38,15,23,14,47,6,31},{1,33,41,25,9,17,49},{19,44,3,36,27,35,12},{10,42,43,34,18,26,4},{30,13,21,5,39,48,22}}

For higher m it is harder as more elements should be swapped but I guess it is not hard to implement an algorithm that would do the job.

Hi @azerbajdzan : this was an absolutely elegant and brilliant solution! The observation to create a magic square first then swap out diagonal endpoints to achive a +/-1, +/-2 offsets! (and you learned this by a 3x3 simplification) My Gosh, I am baffled that great minds still exist! I never gave this a deep thought. But this opens the door to other possibilities.  So I assume a d=1 is always possible for any hjigher n using this method.

Did you manualy do the last sort, or just forgot to include the code for it....

Sorting of rows and columns was done by SortBy[Transpose[   SortBy[{{30, 38, 46, 1, 10, 19, 28}, {39, 47, 7, 9, 18, 27,       29}, {48, 6, 8, 17, 26, 35, 37}, {5, 14, 16, 25, 34, 36,       45}, {13, 15, 24, 33, 42, 44, 2}, {21, 23, 32, 41, 43, 3,       11}, {22, 31, 40, 49, 4, 12, 20}}, Total]], Total]

@azerbajdzan Starting from ResourceFunction["MagicSquare"][7]! Columbus egg!

@A.Kato I have added another approach without Columbus's egg ;-)

A different approach.
Function dms is used to display magic square. Second argument s can be used to set item size to fit numbers in grid nicely.
dms[x_, s_ : 1] := 
 Block[{t1 = Total[x], t2 = Total[x, {2}], d}, 
  If[Differences[t1] == Differences[t2] && 
    Length[Union[Differences[t1]]] == 1, d = t1[[2]] - t1[[1]], 
   d = "x"]; (Grid[#1, ItemSize -> {s, s}, 
      Frame -> {None, 
        None, {{{1, Length[x[[1]]]}, {1, Length[x[[1]]]}} -> 
          True}}] &)[
   Append[Flatten /@ Transpose[{x, t2}], Append[t1, Style[d, Red]]]]]

Then a tool to list possible total sums for n and different distances d.
n = 4;
tot = {d, Table[x[i], {i, n}]} /. 
   Solve[Total[Range[n^2]] == Sum[x[i], {i, n}] && 
     And @@ Table[x[1] + d (i - 1) == x[i], {i, 2, n}] && 
     x[1] >= Total[Range[n]], Append[Table[x[i], {i, n}], d], 
    NonNegativeIntegers] // Reverse


{{0, {34, 34, 34, 34}}, {2, {31, 33, 35, 37}}, {4, {28, 32, 36, 40}},
{6, {25, 31, 37, 43}}, {8, {22, 30, 38, 46}}, {10, {19, 29, 39, 49}},
{12, {16, 28, 40, 52}}, {14, {13, 27, 41, 55}}, {16, {10, 26, 42, 58}}}

{2, {31, 33, 35, 37}} means distance is 2 and total sums are {31, 33, 35, 37}.
The total sums can be used for to in the following searching algorithm.
to = {31, 33, 35, 37};
n = Length@to;

np = 1000;
ra = Partition[RandomSample[Range@(n^2)], n];
por = (# - to & /@ ({Total[#], Total[#, {2}]} &@ra)) // Abs // 
    Flatten // Total;

Monitor[While[np != 0,
  h = False;
  Do[
   np = ((# - 
            to & /@ ({Total[#], 
              Total[#, {2}]} &@(ra /. {r1 -> r2, r2 -> r1}))) // Abs //
        Flatten // Total);
   If[np < por, por = np; ra = ra /. {r1 -> r2, r2 -> r1}; 
    h = True], {r1, n^2}, {r2, n^2}];
  If[h == False, ra = Partition[RandomSample[Range@(n^2)], n];
   por = (# - to & /@ ({Total[#], Total[#, {2}]} &@ra)) // Abs // 
      Flatten // Total;]], por]
ra
((# - to & /@ ({Total[#], Total[#, {2}]} &@(%))) // Abs // Flatten // 
  Total)
ra // dms[#, 1.9] &


{{2, 16, 12, 1}, {5, 3, 10, 15}, {11, 8, 9, 7}, {13, 6, 4, 14}}

0


Here are found squares for n=4, 5, 6, 7 one example for particular d.




Here a bit bigger example for n=16 and d=14. It took quite some time. If searching algorithm does not return any output for a long time it should be quited by Alt + ..


Cool stuff again @azerbajdzan !!  Did you notice the EVEN squares have no d=1 levels!  I had thought they all do! they only have the EVEN d's ! Odd squares have ALL the d's!   This seems to be the pattern

@Steve237 Yes, for even squares it is impossible to have odd distances.

Good point! odd or even numbers when added together Even number of times produce Even results, hence their distances can never be odd! Thx
